# Form still submits after trying to call event.preventDefault()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

Hi I'm trying to post my form data via ajax.
But I still want to make use of the default validation and to show the default messages from html form. So the form shows the default error messages of the form but when the form is correctly filled it does a regular form submut instead of executing the preventDefault and then my ajax method. How come it doesn't stop from submiting ? I don't understand, can anybody help me out, that would be great.

my html form:

```
<form id="add_address">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="address_address_name" required placeholder="Naam adres*" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="address_address" required placeholder="Straat + Nr*" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="address_zipcode" required placeholder="Postcode*" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="address_city" required placeholder="Plaats*" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="address_phone" placeholder="Telefoon" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="address_email" required placeholder="Email*" />
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default right">Save</button>
</form>
```

my javascript:

```
$('#add_address button').on('click',submit_form_address);

function submit_form_address(event){

   form = $('#add_address');
   console.log("yes here:"+ $(form)[0].checkValidity());

   if( $(form)[0].checkValidity() != false){
      event.preventDefault();
      add_address(form);
   }
}


function add_address(p_Form){

    var url = '/addresses';
    data = new FormData($(p_Form)[0]);

    $.ajax({
        url:url,
        method:'POST',
        data:data,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success:success_add_address,
        error:error
    });
}
```

Solution for me: I now using this way and this way is working for me to use default validation of the html form and do a custom submit through ajax.

```
$(document).on('submit', '#add_address', function(e){
    add_address($(this));
    e.preventDefault(); 
});
```

Comment: try handling `submit` event instead of `click` event.

Comment: or change `<button type="submit"` to `<button type="button"`

Comment: `$('#add_address').on('submit',function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
});`

Comment: You're preventing the default click - not the default submit (so handle submit as @gurvinder372 mentions) or change button type so it doesn't submit.

Comment: Also try <button type="button" if you want to manually submit the form. That way you wont need the preventDefault call

Comment: That said, preventing the default on the `click` of a submit button should also prevent form submission on a compliant browser (since the default action of a submit button is to submit the form: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-button-type-submit-state) But given the above, it makes more sense to handle the `submit` event than the `click`.

Comment: Note that your code is falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) -- declare your variables (such as `form`). This *probably* isn't the problem, although thinking about it, it could be if you have an element with `id="form"` somewhere, or a form field with `name="form"`...

Comment: add `return false` in your submit function

Comment: @diavolic: There's no need to do that if calling `preventDefault`.

Comment: [Works for me](https://jsfiddle.net/gfras7b6/1/). Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score -1):

```
    if( $(form)[0].checkValidity() != false){               
           add_address(form);
           event.preventDefault();
         }
```

// OR

```
    if( $(form)[0].checkValidity() != false){               
           add_address(form);
           return false;
         }
```